# oracle.mds.config.MDSConfigurationException in a tomcat JSF application

Tags: jsf, tomcat, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a JSF application developed using Oracle jDeveloper ADF framewrok. Now I'm trying to getting this to run on TomCat server. and getting this error in catalina log. Can someone help me to find out what's causing this.

```
    SEVERE: buildComponentConfigList
        oracle.mds.config.MDSConfigurationException: MDS-01329: unable to load element "{http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config}mds-component-config"    
        cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'audit-config'. One of '{"http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":type-config, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":file-type-config, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":event-notification, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":untyped-dependency-config}' is expected.
            at oracle.mds.internal.config.ConfigurationUtils.getBeanFromElement(ConfigurationUtils.java:244)
            at oracle.mds.config.MDSComponentConfig.loadFromElement(MDSComponentConfig.java:332)
            at oracle.mds.config.MDSComponentConfig.<init>(MDSComponentConfig.java:488)
            at oracle.mds.config.MDSComponentConfig.getMDSComponentConfigList(MDSComponentConfig.java:168)
            at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFMDSConfig.buildComponentConfigList(ADFMDSConfig.java:77)
            at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFMDSConfig.getDefaultMDSInstance(ADFMDSConfig.java:446)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at oracle.adf.share.config.FallbackConfigImpl.getMDSInstance(FallbackConfigImpl.java:64)
            at oracle.adf.share.config.FallbackConfigImpl.getDefaultMDSInstance(FallbackConfigImpl.java:95)
            at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigImpl.getMDSInstance(ADFConfigImpl.java:648)
            at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigImpl.getMDSInstance(ADFConfigImpl.java:628)
            at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFContextMDSConfigHelperImpl.getMDSInstance(ADFContextMDSConfigHelperImpl.java:274)
            at oracle.adf.share.ADFContext.getMDSInstanceAsObject(ADFContext.java:1757)
            at oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFContext.initialize(ServletADFContext.java:494)
            at oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFContext.initThreadContext(ServletADFContext.java:401)
            at oracle.adf.mbean.share.connection.ADFConnectionLifeCycleCallBack.contextInitialized(ADFConnectionLifeCycleCallBack.java:74)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4236)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4739)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
        Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
         - with linked exception:
        [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'audit-config'. One of '{"http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":type-config, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":file-type-config, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":event-notification, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":untyped-dependency-config}' is expected.]
            at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:315)
            at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:505)
            at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:317)
            at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:288)
            at oracle.mds.internal.config.ConfigurationUtils$1.run(ConfigurationUtils.java:207)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at oracle.mds.internal.config.ConfigurationUtils.getBeanFromElement(ConfigurationUtils.java:202)
            ... 42 more
        Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'audit-config'. One of '{"http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":type-config, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":file-type-config, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":event-notification, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":untyped-dependency-config}' is expected.
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:417)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3182)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1806)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:550)
            at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:78)
            at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60)
            at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:135)
            at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:228)
            at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:265)
            at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:234)
            at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:111)
            at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:305)
            ... 46 more
        Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM oracle.adf.mbean.share.connection.ADFConnectionLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
        SEVERE: ADFConnection mbean not registered for defaultApplicationName. 
        Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM oracle.adf.mbean.share.connection.ADFConnectionLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
        SEVERE: 
        oracle.jrf.UnknownPlatformException: JRF is unable to determine the current application server platform.
            at oracle.jrf.ServerPlatformSupportFactory.getInstance(ServerPlatformSupportFactory.java:79)
            at oracle.adf.mbean.share.connection.ADFConnectionLifeCycleCallBack.contextInitialized(ADFConnectionLifeCycleCallBack.java:81)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4236)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4739)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
        Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM oracle.adf.mbean.share.config.ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
        SEVERE: Failed to register config mbean for defaultApplicationName.
        Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM oracle.adf.mbean.share.config.ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
        SEVERE: 
        oracle.jrf.UnknownPlatformException: JRF is unable to determine the current application server platform.
            at oracle.jrf.ServerPlatformSupportFactory.getInstance(ServerPlatformSupportFactory.java:79)
            at oracle.adf.mbean.share.config.ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack.contextInitialized(ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack.java:79)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4236)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4739)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
        Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM oracle.bc4j.mbean.BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
        SEVERE: Not able to get Deployment Name
        Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM oracle.bc4j.mbean.BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
        WARNING: MDS-01702: The method getBean() is not valid for metadata object /demo/fusion/model/common/bc4j.xcfg - it is allowed on only bean metadata objects.
        oracle.mds.exception.MDSRuntimeException: MDS-01702: The method getBean() is not valid for metadata object /demo/fusion/model/common/bc4j.xcfg - it is allowed on only bean metadata objects.
            at oracle.mds.core.MetadataObject.getBean(MetadataObject.java:327)
            at oracle.adf.share.jndi.MDSBackingStore.getMOBean(MDSBackingStore.java:558)
            at oracle.bc4j.mbean.RuntimeMXBeanImpl.init(RuntimeMXBeanImpl.java:120)
            at oracle.bc4j.mbean.RuntimeMXBeanImpl.<init>(RuntimeMXBeanImpl.java:110)
            at oracle.bc4j.mbean.RuntimeMXBeanImpl.<init>(RuntimeMXBeanImpl.java:101)
            at oracle.bc4j.mbean.BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack.contextInitialized(BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack.java:135)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4236)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4739)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
        Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
        INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.1 ( 20130709-1453 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.1@12065) for context '/ADFMinimal_ViewController_webapp1'
        Sep 10, 2016 12:43:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
        SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
        com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:449)
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4236)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4739)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKit.<init>(UnifiedRenderKit.java:129)
            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKit.createRenderKit(UnifiedRenderKit.java:113)
            at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(UnifiedRenderKitFactory.java:59)
            at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.CoreRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(CoreRenderKitFactory.java:55)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.addRenderKits(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:240)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.process(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:159)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.process(ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.java:270)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ValidatorConfigProcessor.process(ValidatorConfigProcessor.java:120)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ConverterConfigProcessor.process(ConverterConfigProcessor.java:126)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ComponentConfigProcessor.process(ComponentConfigProcessor.java:117)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:340)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:239)
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:435)
            ... 25 more
        Sep 10, 2016 12:43:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
        SEVERE: Error listenerStart
        Sep 10, 2016 12:43:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
        SEVERE: Context [/ADFMinimal_ViewController_webapp1] startup failed due to previous errors
        Sep 10, 2016 12:43:13 AM javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager getFactory
        SEVERE: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
        Sep 10, 2016 12:43:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
        SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
            at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:140)
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:310)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4275)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4920)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4784)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.jav

a:414)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no official solution how to make ADF application work properly on Tomcat.
Today Oracle supports ADF only with: Weblogic, Websphere(only 7.x for ADF 11) and GlassFish servers.

You can see the problem in this line from your stacktrace:

> oracle.jrf.UnknownPlatformException: JRF is unable to determine the current application server platform.

In theory you can try to start Tomcat with ADF runtime libraries. But there is a huge problem to find out all jars and their dependencies.